# Deploying Django on VPS but getting nginx 502 Bad Gateway: recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm trying to deploy a Python3 Django project on a Digital Ocean droplet using one-click install for Django. I've uploaded everything and changed the files to what they should be (to my knowledge) but when I go to my site in my web browser, I get a page that says '502 Bad Gateway' from nginx. When I look in my error log, I get the following error:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

I'm not sure what this means exactly, so I'm hoping someone here can help. I have however changed the 'python' command to run python3 because it was set up for python2 and an older version of Django. By 'changing the command', I did the following:

```
Go to /usr/bin, remove python and pip, and create new links

ln -s python3 python

ln -s pip3 pip
```

I've updated Django and dependencies. Are the any config files I should edit? Perhaps a python path for nginx?

I'm a bit in over my head here, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How did you "change the python command"? That sounds like something you should never do, although I highly doubt it is relevant to your problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ah, sorry for not clarifying that. I'll edit.